# Anylogic / Is there a way for a car to move the shortest Path distance of Nodes by itself using Statechart?

Tags: anylogic

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQPOi.png)
in the pic, Agent car is in the center Node, and there are 5 additional Nodes. Compared the Path length of Nodes using JAVA coding in Statechart, and succeeded to MoveTo shortest node.

when the number of Nodes has increased, how Agent car calculates the length of the Path on itself. I want to move to Node of Path(the shortest distance among many Nodes). For example, like navigation, I want to see the car move by calculating on its own.

I want to know how to implement it with Statechart. If the above method is not possible, please let me know how to use the library most efficiently. (ex. Martial Handling, Process Modeling)

Comment: sorry, this is really hard to understand. Could you refine the descriptions, take out these * signs and make clear what you need? thx.

Comment: I want make Agent's own calculations of shortest path in many nodes. and move to the node(have shortest path)
I'm working on a project at work with Statechart, Parameter, Variable block, so I need a way to solve it with Statechart or JAVA coding inside Agent. Thank you.

Comment: See my tutorial here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9B_1Eph6ecU&t=1s . Quite advanced but you can do whatever you like with that setup